Clarification on Projected DOS Plot for Separate s and p Orbitals of Vanadium in PyProcar
I have been following the example from the user guide for this, which plots the stacked projected DOS of the d orbitals of Sr (Sr = [4,5,6,7,8]), the p orbitals of O (O = [1,2,3]), and the combined s and p orbitals of V (V = [0,1,2,3]). The PyProcar command I am currently using is as follows:
pyprocar.dosplot(code='vasp', dirname='vasp_dir', mode='stack', colors=['lawngreen', 'orangered', 'royalblue'], items=dict(Sr=[4, 5, 6, 7, 8], O=[1, 2, 3], V=[0, 1, 2, 3]),orientation='horizontal', elimit=[-4, 4], plot_total=True)

And the plot looks like this 
However, instead of plotting the s and p orbitals of Vanadium together, I would like to plot them separately e.g., V_s and V_p. Could you kindly suggest how I should modify the PyProcar code to achieve this?
Thank you for your time, and I look forward to your response.
